# Google Analytics xlsx to sql - ssis vs2013

Tags: ssis

I have google analytics xlsx files downloaded in a local folder and trying to import it to sql using ssis in vs 2013.

I am using OLE DB source with connection manager settings:-
Provider as office 12.0
file name - file in local path
advanced extended properties - Excel 12.0
Delay validation- true for data flow task etc...
installed Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable

google https://dataintegrity.wordpress.com/2009/10/16/xlsx/

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e8b5f7c6-bd4f-4f6a-aeef-a011e4b47146/opening-a-rowset-for-failed-check-that-the-object-exists-in-the-database?forum=sqlintegrationservices

But always getting error as below:-

### TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio

Exception from HRESULT: 0xC02020E8
Error at Data Flow Task [OLE DB Source [2]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.

Error at Data Flow Task [OLE DB Source [2]]: Opening a rowset for "Dataset1$" failed. Check that the object exists in the database.

What other settings i am missing? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The error is a generic one and can exist for various reasons. Check the following:

Set the DelayValidation property of the OLE DB Source adapter to True.

Check the xlsx file manually to see if it actually has data

Check data types, lengths in the xlsx file as there may be bad rows.

Delete the Data Flow Task, and create a new one.

Comment: I did tried those steps with 15 different  GA reports and all are giving same errors. Does it means all have some bad rows. i also created a report manually and that works fine.

Comment: also tried sql command - SELECT        Country, City, [Number of Sessions per User]
FROM            [dataset1$A2:D]             error- this table contacins cells that are outside range og cells defined in the spreedsheet